# Scraping a paginated website with fixed url for every page (Python)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am not familiar with HTML but I will do my best to explain what I need. I am scraping a [website](http://www.metrocuadrado.com/web/inmuebles/venta/) that is paginated. If one goes to the bottom one finds a 'Siguiente' (next in spanish) button that will lead to the next page. When doing so, the URL remains unchanged. Is there any way to tell Python to open the next page?

I want to do this:

```
(already done)
open the website,
do sth with the info there,
(having trouble because there is no URL of the next page)
go to the next page,
repeat...
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have a look at using mechanise https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/0.2.5  it makes the whole process very simple.  Effectively allows you to find and click buttons, simplifies logging etc..  from within Python. I use it in combination with beautiful soup for the data extraction.

Comment: @Vladimir, the link you posted gives *Access Denied* so your question is basically unanswerable, also mechanize does not run Js so I don't see how that is going to help, the only hope you have is to simulate any ajax requests or use something like Selenium to get what you want.